# Undefined behavior when adding a const with const_cast?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, const-correctness, const-cast

This question is regarding the behavior I observed while using `const_cast` for making a `char *` `const char *`. I am aware that this casting is done implicitly and **t** working for me when the cast is being done implicitly.

The problematic code is:

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main() {
    const char * org_str = NULL;
    org_str = const_cast<const char*>(getenv("ENV_VAR")); // PROBLEM !!
}
```

As per the [Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv) `getenv()` takes `const char *` and returns `char*`. So, as per my understanding of const-correctness, I can do a const cast on `char*` without any issues.

So, my question is, why `const_cast` here giving me a UB (code is crashing) but as expected without `const_cast`(implicit casting) its working fine(So the problem has to be with the use of `const_cast`) ?

Please note, I know implicit cast is the way to go here, through this post I require the answer specifically for the behavior observed here.

EDIT:

Since the bug is non reproducible by fellow So'ers, I am assuming this as some weird runtime/compiler issue. But, do let me know if there is any mention of problems such as this in the standard.

For the time being I am accepting Mike's answer.

Comment: Are you sure this works at all?  Since `getenv` is a function, this shouldn't compile because you can't cast a function pointer to a `const char*` by adding or removing `const`.  Similarly, this `const_cast` is *adding* `const`, not removing it, so it should be safe.  Can we see your actual code?

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  http://sscce.org

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code. There must be something wrong with either your compiler, or some other part of your program.

Comment: Yeah, even I thought it must be elsewhere.But it is working very fine since I removed the const_cast.

Comment: This code compiles and runs for me on GCC 4.6.2/Linux.

Comment: @Christoph: It work for me too when build in debug mode. Its with optimized mode that it is not working

Comment: Hmm, it also works in optimized mode for me. Command line: `g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wall -W -std=c++98 -pedantic -o bla bla.cpp` where `bla.cpp` contains your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are casting the function pointer, not the pointer returned by the function. Call the function first with (), *then* cast the result.

**EDIT:** I can't reproduce the problem. Here's the code I used:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    const char * org_str = NULL;
    org_str = const_cast<const char*>(getenv("PATH"));
    cout << "Got: " << org_str << endl;
}
```

Here's what I got:

```
$ g++ foo.cc -o foo.app
$ ./foo.app
Got: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
$
```

BTW, the assignment to NULL is unnecessary; recommended practice is to use one of:

```
const char *org_str = const_cast<const char*>(getenv("PATH"));

const char *org_str(const_cast<const char*>(getenv("PATH")));

const char *org_str(getenv("PATH"));
```

Comment: If the OP tried to cast a function pointer with `const_cast`, it wouldn't even compile.  The code posted is not what the OP is actually running.

Comment: I have edited the code. Please check, I want to get an env var "ENV_VAR".

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `const_cast<>` to make something const, you only need it to take away the const-ness.

Also I don't believe the code you have there is correct at all, since `getenv` is a function and it looks like you're using it as a variable. Perhaps something like this would work:

```
const char * org_str = getenv("name-of-env");
```

Comment: I know I dont need cons_cast, but whats wrong when I use it, thats the question. Also, I have edited the code.

Comment: I tried your sample code in Visual Studio 2010 but nothing went wrong. My suspicion is that something else is going wrong.

Comment: @It work for me too when build in debug mode. Its with optimized mode that it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's, as far as I understand, not the return value of getenv you should cast, but the const char you have. As org_str is constant, you can't assign to it without using const_cast, which means you would need to do something like:

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main() {
    const char * org_str = NULL;
    const_cast<char*>(org_str) = getenv("ENV_VAR"); // NO PROBLEM !!
}
```

EDIT: As for having const_cast on the getenv, it makes no sense, as you don't assign to that and therefor will not have any violations of the const expression, as

```
org_str = getenv("ENV_VAR") will give you.
```

Comment: It's kind of weird, I agree. But this is what is done in: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast Another use is of course to cast a const object, to change it's values. At least that's the only two use cases I have seen.

Comment: I tried this and got: `warning: target of assignment not really an lvalue; this will be a hard error in the future`.

Comment: @martiet: I think lvalue casts can only be used with references. Need to dig the standard though ;)